# Convert Table name from lower case to upper case

Tags: sql-server, uppercase, case-conversion

The script below shows an example query for data that have been converted from lower case, but it only changed the data on one column in the table.

```
Use MYF601T
Go

UPDATE ROAD_LINE
SET NAM = UPPER(NAM)
```

However, the following script that I'm trying to write is to convert all on all columns on all tables, but the result generated with errors.

```
Use MYF601T
Go

UPDATE INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
SET INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES.TABLE_SCHEMA = UPPER(INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES.TABLE_SCHEMA
```

How to do this for all tables and all columns inside?

Comment: `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` are **system-level** catalog views - you **CANNOT** directly manipulate those! What are you *really* trying to do here??

Comment: _"the result generated with errors"_ if you write something like this always include the error message

Comment: No, its just that i want to change all data that in lower case to uppercase.

Comment: I already complete this query, but its only for one column.

Comment: You won't achieve this way you try. You probably need Dynamic-SQL built based on `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` which pulls table names and columns, build update statement and execute it

Answer (score 0):

If for whather reasons you want to convert your tables names to Upper case, you can:

- use a cursor that will select the tables you want to rename
- loop through the table list
- rename it using [sp_rename](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188351%28v=SQL.120%29.aspx) or update it

Note that you have to update the Select in the cursor to suit your needs (select column or table name you want, ...)

This will rename tables:

```
declare @TABLE_NAME sysname, @TABLE_SCHEMA sysname
declare @TABLE sysname, @newName sysname
declare table_cursor Cursor
    For Select TABLE_NAME, TABLE_SCHEMA From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES Where TABLE_NAME like 'xyz%' -- and TABLE_SCHEMA like ...

open table_cursor
Fetch Next From table_cursor Into @TABLE_NAME, @TABLE_SCHEMA;

While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
Begin
    Set @TABLE = quotename(UPPER(@TABLE_SCHEMA)) + '.' + quotename(UPPER(@TABLE_NAME))
    Set @newName = UPPER(@TABLE_NAME)
    print 'rename ' + @TABLE + ' to ' + @newName
    -- uncomment next like if you really want to rename them
    --exec sp_rename @TABLE, @newName
    Fetch Next From table_cursor Into @TABLE_NAME, @TABLE_SCHEMA;
End

Close table_cursor
Deallocate table_cursor
```

If you want to update all columns xyz in table zyx, you can use this:

```
declare @TABLE_NAME sysname, @TABLE_SCHEMA sysname, @COLUMN_NAME sysname
declare @TABLE sysname, @sql nvarchar(max)
declare table_cursor Cursor
    For Select TABLE_NAME, TABLE_SCHEMA, COLUMN_NAME From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    Where COLUMN_NAME like 'xxx' -- and data_type  '' ... and TABLE_NAME like 'xyz%' ...  and TABLE_SCHEMA like ...

open table_cursor
Fetch Next From table_cursor Into @TABLE_NAME, @TABLE_SCHEMA, @COLUMN_NAME;

While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
Begin
    Set @TABLE = quotename(@TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + quotename(@TABLE_NAME)
    set @sql = 'Update ' + @TABLE + ' set ' + @COLUMN_NAME + ' = UPPER(' + @COLUMN_NAME + ')'
    print @sql
    -- uncomment next like if you really want to execute them
    --exec sp_executesql @sql
    Fetch Next From table_cursor Into @TABLE_NAME, @TABLE_SCHEMA, @COLUMN_NAME;
End

Close table_cursor
Deallocate table_cursor
```

Comment: Read what OP want to achieve, he wants to UPPERCASE data in table NOT table/column name

Comment: thanks but not so obvious aside from one comment. I added a second query and they answer both type of question.

Comment: The first script work fine... But the second modify THE CONTENT of the column. Not their name

Answer (score 0):

Use a dynamic query to update all the column content to `upper` case.

**Query**

```
declare @query varchar(max)

select @query =
stuff
(
    (
        select ';update ' + table_name + ' ' +
        'set ' + column_name + ' = upper(' + column_name + ')'
        from information_schema.columns
        where table_name = 'ROAD_LINE'
        order by table_name,column_name
        for xml path('')
     )
, 1, 1, '')

execute(@query);
```